# Problem with subject encoding when sending an email

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding, jakarta-mail, velocity

I'm sending an email and I'm receiving it correctly but the encoding of the subject is not correct. I'm sending "invitación" but I'm receiving "invitaci?n". The content of the message is OK.

The content of the message is coming from a transformation of a Velocity Template while the subject is set in a String variable.

I've googled around and I've seen that some people says that MimeUtility.encodeText() could solve the problem, but I have had no success with it.

How can I solve the problem? This is the code I have so far.

```
String subject = "Invitación";
String msgBody = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "/vmTemplates/template.vm", "UTF-8", model);

Properties props = new Properties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

try {
    String encodingOptions = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setHeader("Content-Type", encodingOptions);
    msg.setFrom(new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(emailFrom));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailTo));

    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(msgBody, encodingOptions);
    Transport.send(msg);

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        ...
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        ...
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

JavaMail has perhaps a little too much abstraction, and you're falling victim to it here.  When you use

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

you're *creating* a `MimeMessage` object but treating it as a `Message` object.  `Message` has only a `setSubject(String subject)` method, which uses the platform default charset to encode the subject.  If the platform default can't encode it, you get `?` characters in the resulting header.  `MimeMessage`, however, has a `setSubject(String subject, String charset)` method which will allow you to specify the charset you want to use to encode the subject.  So just switch your code to

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setHeader("Content-Type", encodingOptions);
msg.setFrom(new javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress(emailFrom));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailTo));

msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
```

and it should work.

Comment: The only shipped subclass of `Message` is `MimeMessage`.  I'm doubting that anyone's implemented another subclass.  JavaMail would be less grotty if they'd just collapsed `javax.mail` and `javax.mail.internet` -- that extra layer of abstraction just means you're constantly casting to the subclass.

Comment: This did not resolve my problem (sending the £ symbol in the subject line)

Comment: @Mark: You tried `msg.setSubject("\u00a3", "UTF-8")` and it didn't encode the subject properly?  What was in the resulting Subject header?

Comment: Sorry. I fixed my problem, was not related to the subect encoding - it was related to reading a file that was used to populate subject, so my subject string was incorrect before adding to message.

Comment: @dkarp: I always thought the spelling was "Groddy" ... I stand corrected :)

Comment: Somehow I don't see the signature with 2 params. @edyluisrey answer solved problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

you can use, it works

```
msg.setSubject(MimeUtility.encodeText("string", "UTF-8", "Q"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try: `msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF8");`

Comment: There is not this method for javax.mail.Message. I'm using Java Mail API provided by AppEngine.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I didn't noticed that is related to AppEngine!

Comment: I had forgotten at first. I edited the post later to tag it as AppEngine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only thing which worked is changing the system locale to the one which supports desired character set.
Before that I tried many different ways including the accepted answer from this thread, but none of them helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented emailService in one of my project and I am using MimeMessageHelper & MimeMailMessage for the same. Please refer to code as below.

```
private String sendEmail() {
  MimeMessage mimeMessage = EmailSenderFactory.INSTANCE.getEmailSender().createMimeMessage();
  MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
  mimeMessageHelper.setTo("YourToEmailId");
  mimeMessageHelper.setFrom("YourFromEmailId");
  mimeMessageHelper.setBcc("YourBccEmailId");
  mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("YourEmailSubject");
  mimeMessageHelper.setText("YourEmailContent", true);
  mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment("DocumentName", new ByteArrayDataSource("Document data in byte[]", "Document Content Type"));
  MimeMailMessage mimeMailMessage = new MimeMailMessage(mimeMessageHelper);
  return EmailSenderFactory.INSTANCE.getEmailSender().send(mimeMailMessage);
}
```